# What is the best way to restart bitcoind after a bitcoin.conf change (Ubuntu 23.10)

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind, full-node, ubuntu, bitcoin.conf

I'm curious about the recommended way to restart a systemd service after a configuration change or if there is any particular issue with running `sudo service bitcoin restart` to have the config change take effect?

Answer (score 1):

Bitcoin Core reads the bitcoin.conf file on every startup, so if you have it (properly) configured as a systemd service, restarting it that way will indeed make the configuration change take effect.

Comment: Thank you for your response! I do understand this, was also inquiring to see if there are better ways to go about things i.e. be offline for the least amount of time or avoid restarting at a pivotal time unknowingly due to some event occurring simultaneously... If you have any thoughts there it would be much appreciated.

Comment: There is no pivotal time such that Bitcoin Core would be unwilling to shut down when requested. Recall from the Bitcoin white paper that "nodes can leave and rejoin the network at will".

Comment: Thank you very much. Appreciate your time.